# Import an image from an archive

Tags: docker, openshift

I need to deploy selenium/standalone-chrome image to docker.
The problem is that I use corporative openshift with private registry. There is no possibility to upload image to registry or load it thru the docker (docker service is not exposed).
I managed to export tar file from local machine using command 'docker save -o'. I uploaded this image to artifactory as an artifact and now can download it.
Question: how can I create or import image based on a binary  archive with layers?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: This seems to be a pretty closed up environment. Why don't you ask your system administrator how to do it correctly?

Comment: I wonder why you can not use `docker load`?

Answer (score 0):

Even you're using OpenShift, you can proceed to Docker push since the registry is exposed by default: you need your username (`oc whoami`) along with the token `oc whoami --show-token`.

Before proceeding, make sure you have an *Image Stream* since it's mandatory in order to push images.

Once obtained these data, proceed to login from your host:

```
docker login -u `oc whoami` -p `oc whoami --show-token` registry.your.openshift.fqdn.tld:443
```

Now, you just need to build your image

```
docker build . -t registry.your.openshift.fqdn.tld:443/your-image-stream/image-name:version
```

Finally, push it!

```
docker push registry.your.openshift.fqdn.tld:443/your-image-stream/image-name:version
```